# Formatting float gives 0.00

Tags: python, formatting, decimal

I am trying to format a float value and cant seem to get it to work like others.

The float is coming from tow lists zipped together, sorting in reverse and then printing the first (largest result). However when I go to format the result, I get 0.00 the output.

Is this because using zip produces a tuple, which cant be modified?

```
if menu_choice == '2':
 ghg_floats = []
 for x in ghg_1:
    ghg_floats.append(float(x))

gdp_floats = []
for x in ghg_2:
    gdp_floats.append(float(x))

ghg_floats_round = list(map(lambda x: round(x, ndigits=2), ghg_floats))
gdp_floats_round = list(map(lambda x: round(x, ndigits=2), gdp_floats))

result = list(map(truediv, ghg_floats_round, gdp_floats_round))

del carbon_data[0]
zipped = list(zip(result, countries))

from operator import itemgetter as itmg
zipped.sort(reverse=True)

aval = zipped[0][0]
print(aval)
aval = float(zipped[0][0])
f_aval = "{0:,.2f}".format(aval)
print((f_aval))
```

Result:

```
Welcome to the main menu. Please select an option
(1) CO2 emissions breakdown
(2) Maximum emissions per GDP
(3) Top 10 GHG countries
(4) Energy consumption distribution
(5) Exit
Enter your choice: 2
8.72491229236659e-09
0.00
```

So the calculations are being done, the two lists are being joined and then the highest value is being sorted and then selected, but when I go to format the result it does not format, and displays 0.00. Does it have something to do with the amount of trailing characters?

Comment: Your `aval` has 8 zeros after the decimal point, thor formatting `.2f` formats such that you get only 2 decimal places after the decimal point. Depending on how you want to show your data, you could for example use `.2e` to get your number formatted as `8.72e-09`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @MechanicPig expected output is the float above the 0.00, to two decimals. So im looking for 8.72 in this instance.

Comment: @Talon sorry not sure what you mean >Your aval has 8 zeros after the decimal point. 

For some reason, using the .2f method shown above gives me a 0.00 output, not the expected 8.72. Any reason why?

Comment: 8.72491229236659e-09 is not, as you seem to think,  nearly equal to 8.72. It is 0.00000000872491229236659, and the nearest value to that with 2 decimals is 0.00.  `e-09` can be pronounced *times 10 to the power of minus nine*.

Comment: You may need `{0.:2e}.format(aval)` @FoxPython

Comment: @MechanicPig thanks, that cuts it down to: 8.72e-09. Can I hide the e-09 now?

Comment: You _can_ multiply your value by `1e+9` (meaning1,000,000),  but you'll need to communicate that your result is now in nano-units instead of the unit you were using before, otherwise it may be misleading